# Can I completely convert an Ubuntu desktop installation to a server one? (not just the packages)

Tags: ubuntu, convert

I am aware that the server and desktop editions only differ by the packages installed, and I can install server packages (LAMP etc.) into a desktop edition and get the same thing.

However, I want to be able to completely change my desktop installation into a server edition. e.g: when I type `uname -a` or `lsb_release -a` it is supposed to say Ubuntu server or something. I currently have an 11.10 desktop installation with LAMP stack installed and the info displayed by apache is "Apache blah blah, on (Ubuntu) server.

Where does apache get this information that I am using an Ubuntu desktop installation and not a server one? Is there a config file(s) to edit?

Comment: Seems to me like Apache says "server" already. Even though that has nothing to do with the variant of your Ubuntu release.

Comment: Are you looking to do this **just** to change the banner that Apache is presenting?

Comment: No, not the banner. i think it just means it says it's an apache server. I want to find out the internal settings or config files that distinguishes a desktop installation from a server one.

Comment: The installed package set (including the kernel) is different.  Can you clarify why you're trying to achieve this?  If you want your installation to be the server version, why not just install the server version?

Comment: I just want it to seem as if I installed the server edition without actually doing a clean install. I'm looking to avoid all the fuss involved with re-installing a system. If upgrading/updating to a server edition is a possible option then I'd love to try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most clean solution would not be to replace some packages and install a new (LTS) kernel, but to reinstall your box with an Ubuntu server version. As far as I know, there is no other clean way.

Is there a specific reason why do you want to switch?

Comment: No real reason, just for the formality. I mean it's cooler to think I have an Ubuntu server running instead of a desktop posing as a server. This is a headless server btw.

Comment: I have also experienced problems when re-installing a server edition to my system, something about some packages being corrupt. I have tried various server versions 10.04, 10.10, etc. all with the same errors so I doubt they are really corrupt. The desktop edition installs just fine.

Comment: This is really strange. How did you try to install the server edition?

Comment: Via USB. I have a 500gb HD and partitioned my / with 5gb and /home with the rest. Can the 5gb root partition be the culprit?

Comment: Sorry. Based on what I know, I can only contribute speculations, such as that the 5 GB space were not enough and therefore you received those errors. It would be a good approach to use a 10 GB / (at least).

Comment: It doesn't explain why the desktop edition installs normally though, shouldn't the server edition require less disk space than the desktop for installation? Thanks anyways, I'll try repartitioning my box and give the server installation another go. Seems there is no other way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Ok, I wish you good luck!